# log4net does not write in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp-classic, iis-6, log4net

I have the following log4net configuration:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %ndc - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:/logs/mysystem.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1024MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="Console" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</root>
```

in the local machine it works fine, but when I deploy the web site to the remote server (IIS 6.0) it does not create the log file despite the fact that the system is running.

The AppPool identity is configured to "Network Service".

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grant access "Network Service" access to the logs folder by create a ACE on the folder using the machines name as the principle.  Changing the pool identity to "Local System" can have undesirable effects so I would avoid that.

Another approach is to create a domain user and add this user to the machine IIS_WPG group.  Change the pool identity to use this user.  You can then grant appropriate folder access to this user.

Answer (score 2):

When the application pool is configured to "Network Service" it does not have sufficient permissions to write to the file system, therefore the log file does not created.

Configure the identity of the app pool to "Local System", it will work fine!

Comment: Worth pointing out that "Local System" also grants admin level access to the server where "Network Service" does not and also "Local System" has not access to the network so any ASP code that tries to access, say, a network share would fail.

Comment: I am using ASP .NET, but I think you are right regarding classic ASP

Comment: In this case what I've said also applies to ASP.NET.  In the area of security access rights ASP classic only differs in that it always forces impersonation for script execution.